# Commander.js display help when called with no commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, node-commander

I'm using [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) to write a simple node.js program that interacts with an API. All calls require the use of subcommands. For example:

```
apicommand get
```

Is called as follows:

```
program
  .version('1.0.0')
  .command('get [accountId]')
  .description('retrieves account info for the specified account')
  .option('-v, --verbose', 'display extended logging information')
  .action(getAccount);
```

What I want to do now is display a default message when `apicommand` is called without any subcommands. Just like when you call `git` without a subcommand:

```
MacBook-Air:Desktop username$ git
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
       [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
       [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
       [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
       <command> [<args>]

These are common Git commands used in various situations:

start a working area (see also: git help tutorial)
   clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
   init       Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one
...
```

Comment: Check [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv), it's an array that contains the parameters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do something like this by checking what arguments were received and if nothing other than `node` and `<app>.js` then display the help text.

```
program
  .version('1.0.0')
  .command('get [accountId]')
  .description('retrieves account info for the specified account')
  .option('-v, --verbose', 'display extended logging information')
  .action(getAccount)
  .parse(process.argv)

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
  program.help()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I want to do now is display a default message when apicommand is called without any subcommands. Just like when you call git without a subcommand

The help is automatically displayed from Commander 5 onwards if you call without a subcommand.

(Disclosure: I am a maintainer of Commander.)

Comment: How de we disable that automatic Help?

Answer (score 1):

When you're trying to pass a command, it stores the commands in `process.argv` array.

You can add a conditon like at the end of your code like -:

```
if(process.argv.length  <= 2)
console.log(program.help());
else 
program.parse();
```